# Upload ADF json files to my Data Factory

Tags: .net, json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a number of pipeline/linkedservice/dataset json files and I need to upload them to my Data Factory, opposed to creating new versions and copying the text over. Whats the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using version 1, you can use Visual Studio to do so as shown here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-data-factory-visual-studio-extension-for-authoring-pipelines/

If you are using version 2, you can do this using powershell. First download and install the azure sdk for powershell from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/
Then from powershell, login and select subscription:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "your subs name here"
```

Then with the following command you can upload the json files:

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline -DataFactoryName "your df name" -ResourceGroupName "your RG name" -Name "pipelineName" -DefinitionFile "path to json file"
```

Replace with your Data factory and resource group name.

The same arguments are used to upload linked services and datasets with the commands:

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2LinkedService 
Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Dataset
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for the response. So there is no way to do it through the portal authoring UI?

Comment: If you are using version 1, you can type or copy-paste them from the authoring option. Other than that, there is no way to do so.

Comment: Try to do it with visual studio! I've used it and its quite handy

Answer (score 0):

AzRM is not recommended by microsoft anymore.

You can use the updtaed powershell AZ module to achieve this.

I won't repeat something that is already quite self-explanatory in the official documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/set-azdatafactoryv2pipeline?view=azps-3.3.0