# Data factory version 2

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

Is there any ways to paste Json code to pipeline code in azure data factory version 2?
I am able to copy from pipeline code but no ways to paste there.

Answer (score 1):

I created another answer because I cant format the code in a comment.

If you can get the repository to a folder, you can iterate over a folder and add everything inside with the following code:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\PathToFiles' 
$files | ForEach-Object($_){ 
    Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline -DataFactoryName "your df name" -ResourceGroupName "your RG name" -Name "pipelineName" -DefinitionFile $_.Name 
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks again Martin. One more help. Is it possible to schedule a daily trigger for a pipeline in data factory v2 for past dates?

Comment: It is possible and it will run until its up to date. For example if you program it to run daily since feb, 25th, it will run 4 times in a row because today is march, 1st.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do that, but you can paste the pipeline json and save it into a file, and then upload it with powershell as I explained here: [Upload ADF json files to my Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931495/upload-adf-json-files-to-my-data-factory)

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanku Martin.. Again is it possible to upload to a particular code repository in data factory?

Comment: You can iterate over a folder and add everything inside with the following code:

$files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\PathToFiles'

$files | ForEach-Object($_){
    Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline -DataFactoryName "your df name" -ResourceGroupName "your RG name" -Name "pipelineName" -DefinitionFile $_.Name
}